# How can I jump from if block to else block without using goto?

Tags: c++, if-statement

I am writing a code in which some process is done in if block. But if result of process is not aa expected, I want to execute else block.

```
if(condition1)
{
// Some processing
   if(another condition)
        //Do some task;
   else 
        //Execute else of outer block;
}
else
{
}
```

Comment: Don't. Just don't do it. If you have common code that needs to be executed from multiple places, put it in a function that you call when needed. Or refactor the code.

Comment: Or you can go with `if`, `else if` and `else`? Of course this does not mean you should not put it in a function as suggested.

Comment: @John What led you to conclude that OP is using C++ rather than C?

Comment: @KamalPancholi, you tagged both C and C++, but they're not compatible tags so I removed C. If you want C answers please re-tag the question with only C. Don't put both C and C++. C++ answers might use constructs C doesn't have, and C answers are sometimes poor C++ answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another technique to add to existing answers:

```
bool skip_X = false;
if (condition1)
{
    // Some processing
    if (another condition)
    {
        //Do some task;
        skip_X = true;
    }
}
if (!skip_X)
    ....
```

This avoids evaluating *condition1* twice, which can be problematic if it has side effects or values in the expression could be changed by processing inside the `if` or even in another thread.

---

That said...

> How can I jump from if block to else block without using goto?

The language has `goto` for a reason, and - just like people who say *"how can my constructor report an error without throwing an exception"* - by artificially restricting yourself from using the language feature clearly best suited to your need you create worse code.

Answer (score 9):

You can do this by rewriting your `if` condition:

```
if (condition1) {
    // Some processing
}

if (condition1 && another condition) {
    // Do some task;
} else {
   // Execute else of outer block;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the downvote on this answer - aside from a potential issue with the re-evaluation of `condition1` it's by far the clearest of the answers presented thus far, including mine. It's there something missing?

Comment: Yeah I made a mistake. I'll restore it. I wrote a convoluted answer and thought this was wrong. But in fact, this is a simplified version of mine.

Comment: @AvinKavish: Made a trivial edit to circumvent the locked-in downvote rule.

Answer (score 4):

While the admonitions against such construction are certainly worth considering in earnest, it is possible to do what you ask in a structured way using a switch statement with a fallthru.

e.g.:

```
switch(condition1)
{
    case true:
        // some processing
        if(condition2)
        {
            // Do some task;
            break;
        }
        [[fallthrough]]; // or just comment: fallthru if not using c++17
    case false:
        // execute else of outer block;
}
```

Comment: "explicit int() casts for clarity". i.e., They offer no confusion and may help the reader who sees this usage for the first time.

Comment: For me it is confusion, not clarity.

Comment: OK, sure. Edited.

Comment: Well, that's c++17, so I didn't want to assume (since the OP had originally been tagged C as well, there's no telling what version of C++ this is)

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph 's Answer is also good. But I liked this one more because of possibly better performance. I don't have to evaluate condition1 twice.

Answer (score 3):

You can rely on the *short-circuiting* property of `&&` and the *expression separator operator* `,` and write

```
if (condition1 && (some processing, another condition)){
    // Do some task
} else {
    // The outer block
}
```

Here `some processing` and `another condition` are only evaluated if `condition1` is `true`.

This does have the advantage that `condition1` is only evaluated once which is useful if it has side-effects.

It's also succinct but is not really feasible if `some processing` is not a simple expression (it works nicely if it's a function call).

Comment: In some context, this might not be doable due to a MISRA rule being violated (right-hand side of short-circuit operator cannot have side effect)

Comment: this cannot work. As "some processing" are so many lines of code. And if I put all into one line, it would become unreadable.

Comment: @KamalPancholi: That could well be the case in your case, but answers are not necessarily targetted at the OP. In some instances, such as where `some processing` is brief or a function call, this solution can work well.